# How to merge init.mp4 + .m4s files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, download, video-streaming, video-capture

I'm trying to download a video from a streaming website.

I've found out the video is segmented with MPEG-DASH format. So, I could find a .mpd file, init.mp4 files for video and audio each, and seg-*.m4s files for video and audio each.

How can I combine these files into the original video file?

I've downloaded all the segment m4s files with chrome extension mass downloader but can't find a way of either convert the init.mp4 to m4s so that I can merge it with the other seg-*.m4s files; OR convert the seg-*.m4s files into .mp4 (what I've already tried using ffmpeg, but it seems not be working since ffmpeg needs the header, which is the init.mp4 itself)

What should I do?

Note: I don't know NOTHING about js, ajax, html. So, who answers this, will have to do in laymen words.

Comment: You can just concatenate the init segment with the rest of the fragments of the same stream in the right order to a temporary MP4. You can then defragment it by copying the encoding and remuxing it with FFmpeg to a regular MP4.

Comment: @aergistal thanks for answer me, sir! 

"You can just concatenate the init segment with the rest of the fragments of the same stream in the right order to a temporary MP4"

If I got this part correctly, I should concatenate all the parts in the EXACTLY same order that it shows in the network stream, right?

But I still don't understand how could I "defragment it by copying the encoding and remuxing it with FFmpeg to a regular MP4". I'd apreciate a lot if you could help me with this. Greetings from Brazil!

Comment: See [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) in the FFmpeg documentation. CLI usage: `ffmpeg -i frag.mp4 -c copy some.mp4` where `frag.mp4` is the result of concatenating `init.mp4` and all the `m4s` segments.

Comment: This works great for video. Nowadays sites stream audio and video for each fragment in 2 files. Example "fragment-102-f1-a1-x3.m4s" "fragment-102-f1-v1-x3.m4s". I could only find one "init-f2-v1-x3.mp4" file, none for the audio. No matter in which order I combine the files, I get a video with no sound. Any way to combine the audio with no init file?